# Is it possible to disable Manual Refresh on PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

If I understand correctly, unlike with the Personal Gateway, the Enterprise Gateway allows all the users within the same domain to refresh the data. So my question is: is it possible to disable Manual Refresh? I want to share my dashboard with people in my organization, but I want to avoid having people constantly refreshing the dashboard and consuming my database server resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Report/dashboard in Power Bi, and select Import data not Direct query, don't share dataset with the users, only share report/dashboard with users, this way they will be able to see data but will not be able to refresh it. And you can schedule a time for your source data to get refreshed.